# TextWatcher for multiple EditText fields

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have some code that utilizes the Material Dialogs library; I have a dialog with four EditText fields (email, name, username, password). I want it so that the dialog's *Register* button is disabled unless all fields have at least one character in them.

I searched around, and found a way to do this; unfortunately, it doesn't appear to work. For example, if I pull up the dialog and type anything into any single field, the button becomes enabled. However, if I edit a single field and then edit another field but then delete the text inside one of those fields--the button becomes disabled; the same thing happens if I were to fill out all of the fields, then delete the text inside a single field.

I had thought of utilizing another of the suggestions (which would involve writing my own private inner class)--but I didn't think that would matter considering I'd achieve the same thing (at least, to my knowledge).

```
        //registerDialog is a MaterialDialog object
        final View registerAction = registerDialog.getActionButton(DialogAction.POSITIVE);
        final EditText registerNameInput;
        final EditText registerEmailInput;
        final EditText registerUsernameInput;
        final EditText registerPasswordInput;
        if (registerDialog.getCustomView() != null) {
            registerNameInput = (EditText) registerDialog.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.register_name);
            registerEmailInput = (EditText) registerDialog.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.register_email);
            registerUsernameInput = (EditText) registerDialog.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.register_username);
            registerPasswordInput = (EditText) registerDialog.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.register_password);

            /*
             * TextWatcher lets us monitor the input fields while registering;
             * This make sure we don't allow the user to register with empty fields
             */
            TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    registerAction.setEnabled(s.toString().trim().length() > 0);
                }
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }
            };
            /*We want to watch all EditText fields for input*/
            registerNameInput.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
            registerEmailInput.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
            registerUsernameInput.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
            registerPasswordInput.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
        }
    registerDialog.show();
    registerAction.setEnabled(false); //disabled by default
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to add same TextWatcher in multiple editText ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna Yes; as per other answers on SO--the way I implemented it was supposed to be a way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code as :

First of all you need to **add textwatcher to particular EditText**, which you didn't. Try as below :

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

And then,

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
     if (registerNameInput.getText().toString().length() > 0
                && registerEmailInput.getText().toString().length() > 0
                && registerUsernameInput.getText().toString().length() > 0
                && registerPasswordInput.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                    registerAction.setEnabled(true);
     } else {
         registerAction.setEnabled(false);
     }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. No matter how much I type in, the button remains disabled.

Comment: Check my edited answer or create a class as Shree Krishna suggested in his answer.

Comment: I already tried my own class--and that yielded the same results.

Comment: Your edit works if I add an `else` statement to account for a user deleting text from the field after all of the fields have been filled out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like this, But don't copy I didn't check the code.**

```
public class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    EditText editText, anotherEditText;
    View myView;

// Your constructor
    public MyTextWatcher(EditText editText, EditText anotherEditText View myView) {
        this.editText = editText;
        this.myView = myView
        this.anotherEditText = anotherEditText
    }
 @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
      }

 @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 
      if(anotherEditText.getText().toString().trim().lenght()>0){
           myView.setEnabled(s.toString().trim().length() > 0);
        }
   }

 @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {//something }
```

**Use this class**

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(editText, editText2, myView));
```

Comment: But how is this different than what I'm doing? All I'm doing is creating a class that does the same thing.

Comment: I tried writing my own class to handle it and the same exact thing happens. I didn't think it would work, consider what I said in the above comment.

Comment: What you can do is, pass each of the fields in constructor and check if all the editText is empty or not in the `onTextChanged` method. If not then enable your button.

Answer (score 0):

Making minor change in your implementation you could have achieved that. Instead of adding logic to onTextChanged you could have created one method like

```
private void validateInput(){
        boolean enableButton = true;
        if (registerNameInput.getText() == null || registerNameInput.getText().toString() == null || registerNameInput.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
            enableButton = false;
        }
        if (registerEmailInput.getText() == null || registerEmailInput.getText().toString() == null || registerEmailInput.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
            enableButton = false;
        }
if (registerUsernameInput.getText() == null || registerUsernameInput.getText().toString() == null || registerUsernameInput.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
            enableButton = false;
        }
if (registerPasswordInput.getText() == null || registerPasswordInput.getText().toString() == null || registerPasswordInput.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
            enableButton = false;
        }


        registerAction.setEnabled(enableButton);
    }
```

and called this method in afterTextChanged()

```
TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    validateInput();
                }
            };
```

Benefit of checking one by one is for example for your email input you want to put extra check then you could add like

```
if (registerEmailInput.getText() == null || registerEmailInput.getText().toString() == null || registerEmailInput.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
                enableButton = false;
            }else{
            //put if block to check email input format is correct or not, if not then set enableButton = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use single TextWatcher class for multiple edit-texts, this will works only afterTextChanged(Editable editable)

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        if (editable == editText1.getEditableText()) {
            // do something
        } else if (editable == editText2.getEditableText()) {
            // do something
        }
    }
```